# What's wrong with my dataset to use anova function in R?

Tags: r, model, nested, linear-regression, anova

I want to compare nested models using the **anova** function in R. My dataset:

```
structure(list(Gene = c("ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-1", 
"ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-1", 
"ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-4", 
"ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-4", 
"ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", 
"ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", 
"ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", 
"ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", 
"ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-7", "ID-7", 
"ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", 
"ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", 
"ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-6", "ID-6", 
"ID-7", "ID-7"), mRNA = c(-0.181385669, -0.059647494, 0.104476117, 
-0.052190978, -0.040484945, 0.194226742, -0.501601326, 0.102342605, 
-0.127143845, -0.008523742, -0.102946211, -0.042894028, 0.002922923, 
-0.134394347, -0.214204393, -0.138122686, 0.203242361, 0.097935502, 
0.147068146, -0.089430917, 0.331565412, -0.034572422, -0.129896329, 
0.324191, 0.470108479, -0.027268223, 0.232304713, 0.090348708, 
0.070848402, 0.181540708, -0.502255367, -0.267631441, -0.368647839, 
-0.040910404, -0.003983171, -0.003983171, -0.003983171, -0.14980589, 
-0.119449612, -0.309154214, -0.487589361, 0.272803506, -0.421733575, 
-0.467108567, 0.024868338, -0.156025729, -0.044680175, -0.206716896, 
-0.272014193, -0.230499883, -0.238597397, -0.118130949, 0.349957464, 
0.349957464, 0.349957464, 0.172048587, -0.186226994, 0.16113822, 
-0.293029136, -0.111636253, -0.044189887, 0.081555274, -0.048106079, 
-0.05853566, 0.010407814, -0.066981809, -0.09828484, -0.315190986, 
-0.005102456, 0.221556197, 0.206584568, 0.206584568, 0.206584568, 
0.102649006, -0.011777384, -0.36963487, -0.054853074, -0.230240699, 
-0.210508323, -0.208889919, -0.050763372, 0.023073782, -0.095118984, 
-0.091076071, -0.330257395, 0.102772933, 0.247872038, 0.216357646, 
0.126169901, -0.237278842, -0.066908278, 0.105082639, NA, -0.050061512, 
-0.143484352), Time = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 40L, 40L, 20L, 40L, 40L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 40L, 40L, 
20L, 40L, 40L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 40L, 40L, 20L, 40L, 40L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 40L, 40L, 
20L, 40L, 40L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 40L, 20L, 40L, 40L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 120L, 
120L, 120L, 120L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Condition = c("Irradiated", 
"Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", 
"Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", 
"Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", 
"Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", 
"Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", 
"Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", 
"Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", 
"Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", 
"Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", 
"Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", 
"Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", 
"Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", 
"Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", 
"Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", 
"Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", 
"Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", 
"Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "Irradiated", "reference", 
"reference", "reference", "reference", "reference", "reference", 
"reference", "reference", "reference", "reference")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-95L))
```

And my code:

```
model1 <- lm(mRNA ~ Time, data=GenemRNATimeCondition)
model2 <- lm(mRNA ~ Time + Gene , data=GenemRNATimeCondition)
model3 <- lm(mRNA ~ Time + Gene + Condition, data=GenemRNATimeCondition)
anova_df <- anova(model1,model2,model3)

anova_df[,"model"] <- c("Time","Time+Gene","Time+Gene+Condition")
anova_df
anova(model1,model2,model3)
```

And it gives this error when I run model3:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can only be applied to factor variables with 2 or more levels
```

While when I run

```
anova_df <- anova(model1,model2,model3)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in anova.lmlist(object, ...) : 
  the models were estimated for different sample sizes
```

I know that for the reference values in column "Condition" I have corrispondly have NA values in column "Time" but I do not undestand why this is a problem (if it is a problem). Hope that you can help me to understand in a straightforward way (possibly also from a statistical point of view).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first error, it's telling you that you are missing factors, either because you don't have them or because they were dropped because of missing values. So for ex. if for a specific combination you have only missing values then all the rows of this combination will be dropped, and no such term will be estimated, which will throw an error.

The second error is related, since you group data differently in each model, a different number of rows are being dropped, which results in models being estimated on different subsamples, which is also a problem when comparing the models.

Basically this is because of missing values, you should deal with those before continuing, or adopt another approach.